# Parameterize data input when calling methods from a class

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, ado.net

I am trying to insert some data through a WPF Window and I want to parameterize the input. How can I do this? My code so far:

```
public int insertdetails(string query)
    {
        SqlTransaction trans = null;
        try
        {
            trans = getconnection().BeginTransaction("trInsert");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("", con, trans);
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (a > 0)
            {
                trans.Commit();
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                trans.Rollback("trInsert");
                return 0;
            }
   //....below is the code for button save....//




 dataaccess da = new dataaccess();   //..this is a class with insert method..//
        res = da.insertdetails("insert into staff_table values ('" + txtid.text + "','"+ txtname.text + "','" + txtlname.text + "'");
        if(res > 0)
            messagebox.show("saved!");
        else
            messagebox.show("error!");
```

Comment: you question is really un-clear, can you describe more so we can help you

Comment: @Hakam Fostok:  I want to parameterize the input from textboxes like instead of ('" + txtid.text + "') i use ( @id) and then insert values like ( com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", "txtid.text");

Comment: For that you have to redesign the method signature of `insertdetails()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution to use [SqlParameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to parametrize the [SqlCommand query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can look like this:

First create a general method for the repetitive code, to create the SqlParameter object (in your case it looks, like all parameters are of type string/varchar):

```
public SqlParameter createParameter(string name, string value)
    {
        // create the named parameter
        var sqlParameter = new SqlParameter(name, SqlDbType.VarChar);
        // set the desired value
        sqlParameter.Value = value;
        return sqlParameter;
    }
```

Then write the sql command as a normal query, with the parameter names as palceholders, and add the parameters to the SqlCommand object before executing it:

```
dataaccess da = new dataaccess();
var sqlQuery = new SqlCommand("insert into staff_table values ('@id','@name','@lname')");
sqlQuery.Parameters.Add(createParameter("id", txtid.text));
sqlQuery.Parameters.Add(createParameter("name", txtname.text));
sqlQuery.Parameters.Add(createParameter("lname", txtlname.text));
res = da.insertdetails(sqlQuery);
if(res > 0)
    messagebox.show("saved!");
else
    messagebox.show("error!");
```

The `@` symbol marks the parameters in the sql query. The ADO.NET framework searches for the name in the parameters list and replaces any occurrences with the escaped value. Your code is safe against sql injection attempts.
You must probably change the `insertdetails` method a bit in order to take only the query and the parameters or the SqlCommand as a parameter, instead of just the sql query.

---

You have many options. One would be to change the `query` parameter to `SqlCommand`:

```
public int insertdetails(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        SqlTransaction trans = null;
        try
        {
            trans = getconnection().BeginTransaction("trInsert");
            cmd.Transaction = trans;
            int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (a > 0)
            {
                trans.Commit();
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                trans.Rollback("trInsert");
                return 0;
            }
```

Now you can use the other code from my answer. Another possibility would be to change you code like the answer of @user3185569. Both variants have pros and cons.

Comment: I updated the question with Insertdetails method code..please check and let me know about how can I change my insertdetails method..thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer and changed the signature and the code of the `insertdetails` method.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

```
da.insertdetails(String.Format("insert into staff_table values ('{0}','{1}','{2}')",txtid.text,txtname.text,txtlname.text));
```

in C#6 you can use [String Interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) feature putting `$` at start of string.

```
da.insertdetails($"insert into staff_table values ('{txtid.text}','{txtname.text}','{txtlname.text}')");
```

Comment: my code is prone to sql injection attack , i just want to insert data through parameters which I can't find a good solution for it.

Comment: can you show the `dataaccess` class in your question and clarify what are the parameters? you can edit your question and put more details on it @codefan

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace you insertdetails method to accept the parameters and command. Using **SqlParameter** class is the way to avoid SQL-Injections:

Usage:

```
insertdetails("insert into staff_table", "A", "B", "C");
```

**or**

```
insertdetails("insert into staff_table (col1, col2)", "A", "B");
```

**Code:**

```
public int insertdetails(string command, params string[] parameters)
{
    SqlTransaction trans = null;

    try
    {
        trans = getconnection().BeginTransaction("trInsert");
        SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand()
        {
            Connection = con,
            Transaction = trans
        };


        // Start Building the Parameterized Command
        string insertedValues = String.Empty;

        if (parameters.Any())
        {
            int counter = 1;
            foreach (var paramVal in parameters)
            {
                string paramName = "@param" + counter++;

                sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, paramVal);

                insertedValues += paramName + ",";
            }

            insertedValues = insertedValues.TrimEnd(',');

            insertedValues = String.Format(" VALUES ( {0} )", insertedValues);
        }

        sqlCom.CommandText = String.Format("{0} {1}", command, insertedValues);

        int resCount = sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (resCount > 0)
        {
            trans.Commit();
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            trans.Rollback("trInsert");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Exception Handling
        if (trans != null)
            trans.Rollback();
        return 0;
    }
}
```